# create an object using the form django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-registration

Thank you for looking into this! 
I doing one of those django tutorials from their official website, creating a poll. The poll app and everything is working.

The problem is that after I have created authentication for the users to log in they should be able to create the polls, aka they're given the fields with questions/choices, fil it in and from that data(form) it should a new poll object into the db. I have set up everything, but I cannot figure out how do I write the view for this, as in how do I extract data from the form and add it all as a new poll.

I am using three models, as in tutorial: polls, choices and user (user isn't recognisable either, i mean in the model 'user' i have a variable name = models.ForeignKey(User), I was using django-registration to register the them, but that's not the main problem at the moment).

I hope I am more or less clear, if not, I will be glad to explain again:)

thanks, blargie-bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you starting with generic views.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#decorating-class-based-views
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#editing-views

Comment: thank you:) i have found my problem and i was referencing everything wrong. the manage.py shell has helped me to discover it:)